# How to overcome warning while using stem plot

Tags: python-3.x

UserWarning: In Matplotlib 3.3 individual lines on a stem plot will be added as a LineCollection instead of individual lines. This significantly improves the performance of a stem plot. To remove this warning and switch to the new behaviour, set the "use_line_collection" keyword argument to True.

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to the official documentation for [`matplotlib.pyplot.stem`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html):

> `use_line_collection`: `bool`, optional, default: `False`
>
> If `True`, store and plot the stem lines as a [`LineCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) instead of individual lines. This significantly increases performance, and will become the default option in Matplotlib 3.3. If `False`, defaults to the old behavior of using a list of [`Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) objects.

so, as stated in the warning, simply replace your calls to `stem(...)` by:

```
stem(..., use_line_collection=True)
```

According to the documentation, this won't be necessary starting with Matplotlib 3.3.